# NTFS MAC Times in Hexadecimal

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, timestamp, forensics, hexadecimal

I am using EnCase and a Hex Editor to analyse a virtual drive.

EnCase says that the this hexadecimal: `5FBF60C54F2CCF01`

is the date/time (mm/dd/yy): `02/17/14 09:18:54 (PM)`

I have worked out date/times successfully before, but can't match up the above.

If someone could confirm EnCase is correct and explain it to me, that would be splendid.

Comment: ...what's a "MAC time"?

Comment: Modified, Accessed and Created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se [here](http://articles.forensicfocus.com/2013/04/06/interpretation-of-ntfs-timestamps/). ("Interpretation of NTFS Timestamps", from forensicfocus.com)

> NTFS file timestamps, according to the documentation of the ‘FILETIME’
>   data structure in the Windows Software Development Toolkit, is a 
>   “64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals
>   since January 1, 1601 (UTC)”.
>
> Conversion from this internal format to a format more suitable for
>   human interpretation is performed  by the Windows system call
>   FileTimeToSystemTime(), which extracts the year, month, day, hour,
>   minutes, seconds and milliseconds from the timestamp data. On other
>   platforms (e.g. Unix), or in software that is intentionally
>   platform-independent (e.g. Perl or Java) other methods for translation
>   is be  required.
>
> The documentation of FileTimeToSystemTime(), as well as practical
>   tests,  indicate that the FILETIME value to be translated must be
>   0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF or less.  This corresponds to the time 30828-09-14
>   02:48:05.4775807.

(etc. etc.)

/edit: Though your date would amount to Saturday, Feb 20th of the year **23464** (no typo). Is your NTFS possibly busted?

([Here](http://www.silisoftware.com/tools/date.php)'s a calculator. Use the "filetime" setting, and be sure to enter your numbers in decimal form.)

Comment: Yeah I found the above too, but it just doesn't add up with the data I have. The quoted hex and date isn't actually mine, but mine doesn't add up either.

It would be fine just to accept that it is correct, but I am trying to find an explanation, so I can manually carve the date myself.

Comment: Having spoken with others about this, this is the correct method, the hex string that I had needed to be converted to Little Endian (basically reversed) before being put into this conversion tool. Having done that, the correct date/time should become apparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the puzzle in WinDbg. Just start any program and attach to it.

Then, write your data somewhere into memory:

```
0:001> eq 7731000c  5FBF60C54F2CCF01
```

and interpret it as ole32!FILETIME

```
0:001> dt ole32!FILETIME 7731000c  
 Feb 20 16:57:50 23464
   +0x000 dwLowDateTime    : 0x4f2ccf01
   +0x004 dwHighDateTime   : 0x5fbf60c5
```

As you can see, it is far in the future.

However, it is likely that EnCase display the values byte-wise as written on disk, so you have a LSB/MSB issue. Let's enter the data byte-wise:

```
0:001> eb 7731000c 5F BF 60 C5 4F 2C CF 01
```

Output in 64 bit format, notice that the bytes are in reverse order now.

```
0:001> dq 7731000c  L1
7731000c  01cf2c4f`c560bf5f
```

Interpret as FILETIME:

```
0:001> dt ole32!FILETIME 7731000c
 Feb 18 02:18:54 2014
   +0x000 dwLowDateTime    : 0xc560bf5f
   +0x004 dwHighDateTime   : 0x1cf2c4f
```

Not sure why it is off by a few hours, though. Perhaps that's a time zone issue.